# How to make double seekbar in android?

Tags: android, customization, seekbar

I am building an android application where the user select the a maximum value by seekbar.

I need another button on the same seekbar so that user can select maximum and minimum value from a particular unique seekbar.

Here is my code of single seek bar -

```
package com.ui.yogeshblogspot;

public class CustomSeekBarExActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
 SeekBar bar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
 bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(progress)+"%");

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Here is my xml code of seek bar -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#FFFFFF">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choose Your Progress"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:progressDrawable="@xml/progress"
    android:max="100"
    android:thumb="@xml/thumb"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://github.com/Larpon/RangeSeekBar check this view

Comment: @Andy THanks this is the all function how can I add this code to activity. How this code can be used please help me!!

Comment: The library he posted includes sample code. You should read it.

Comment: @NathanWalters Thanks I had read it.. But how to integrated this in activity.. and how to use this ?? can you help in telling that please

Comment: Did you actually read through the code though? It couldn't be clearer.

Comment: there is a useful library, https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar

Comment: fully customize seekbar http://codingsignals.com/crystal-range-seekbar-in-android/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Android widget class library has only one slider control, seekbar with only one thumb control. Did some research online and found this cool custom widget, range-seek-bar.

you can followed any one of below

https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar

https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

https://github.com/Larpon/RangeSeekBar

Answer (score 15):

Fully Customize two way and single way seek bar you can provide thumb color etc
http://codingsignals.com/crystal-range-seekbar-in-android/

Add in your gradle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.0.0' 
}
```

[image: Two way seekbar]

```
<com.crystal.crystalrangeseekbar.widgets.BubbleThumbRangeSeekbar
android:id="@+id/rangeSeekbar5"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:corner_radius="10"
app:min_value="0"
app:max_value="100"
app:steps="5"
app:bar_color="#F7BB88"
app:bar_highlight_color="#E07416"
app:left_thumb_image="@drawable/thumb"
app:right_thumb_image="@drawable/thumb"
app:left_thumb_image_pressed="@drawable/thumb_pressed"
app:right_thumb_image_pressed="@drawable/thumb_pressed"
app:data_type="_integer"/>
```

Comment: This library is useful.But can you please tell how to set initial value? I mean initially both points should reach at some point .

Comment: This library is quite good, although the radius of the circles don't seem to be configurable, even they have a param (app:corner_radius). So if you don't care the circles are quite big, is a great custom range seek bar.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Now that **[RangeSlider](https://material.io/components/sliders/android#using-sliders)** is officially added to Material Components and [supports desired options](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md#continuous-range-slider) I suggest using that instead of external libraries.

First of all, you should add the view to your XML layout:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
android:id="@+id/range_seek_bar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:valueFrom="0.0"
android:valueTo="100.0"
app:values="@array/initial_slider_values"/>
```

then add initial slider values to arrays

```xml
<resources>
  <array name="initial_slider_values">
    <item>20.0</item>
    <item>70.0</item>
  </array>
</resources>
```

after that you can access RangeSlider values in the code:

```
binding.rangeSeekBar.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, fromUser ->
    Logger.d(slider.values)
}
```

where `values` is a List of floats with 2 member

Answer (score 5):

[image]

From [Here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1272)

```
        <com.appyvet.rangebar.RangeBar
            xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/SearchrangeSeekbarAge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            custom:tickStart="18"
            custom:tickInterval="1"
            custom:tickEnd="70" />


        <com.appyvet.rangebar.RangeBar
            xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/SearchrangeSeekbarHeight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            custom:tickStart="4.5"
            custom:tickInterval="0.10"
            custom:tickEnd="7.0" />


rangebar.setOnRangeBarChangeListener(new RangeBar.OnRangeBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeChangeListener(RangeBar rangeBar, int leftPinIndex,
                int rightPinIndex,
                String leftPinValue, String rightPinValue) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use two seekbar , but you can just do the same function of minimum and maximum by using only one seekbar with having two thumbs over it
Here its a library you can use https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/

You can use by using below code

```
private final Thumb getClosestThumb(float touchX)

{
double xValue = screenToNormalized(touchX);        
return (Math.abs(xValue - normalizedMinValue) < Math.abs(xValue - normalizedMaxValue)) ? Thumb.MIN : Thumb.MAX;
}
```

And in the "public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)",

```
if(pressedThumb == null),
pressedThumb = getClosestThumb(mDownMotionX);
```

Comment: thanks this is an code or an library can you please help me in detail as I am new to it....

Comment: this is library for seekbar

Answer (score 0):

**RangeSeekBar** https://github.com/RanaRanvijaySingh/RangeSeekBar. Also there are other libraries available which offers a lot of customization. If you want to go for more interactive design then look for **Material Range Bar** http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1272.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this link also might be helpful .[range-seek-bar](https://github.com/anothem/android-range-seek-bar) .
There is an explanation about it at [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/p/alangvara/android-range-seek-bar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this libraby](https://github.com/faisalcodes/bidirectional-seekbar) of mine. It comes with a lots of cutomizations. It supports seeking progress in both directions.

[image: bidirection-seekbar-github]