# Vertical Rangebar in Android

Tags: android, canvas, paint, uicomponents, android-vertical-seekbar

As you know there is no two thumbs bar in android. How can we build vertical range bar in android? There are some open source projects but all horizontal.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-verticalseekbar

Comment: @Sudhi it is a seekbar, I want to draw range bar with two thumbs

Comment: Oh I am sorry about that, I didn't see the image completely. Have you tried https://github.com/Jay-Goo/RangeSeekBar

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this library. This might help you

https://github.com/Larpon/RangeSeekBar

Also, have a look at this SO answer [How to make double seekbar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836534/how-to-make-double-seekbar-in-android?answertab=oldest#tab-top)